# Appendage Problem

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, blender-internal-render-engine

[image]

[image]

Hello Blender community, I am attempting to complete a table setting in which I want to place my goblet (image 2) in the table scene in (Image 1). Note, the goblet is it's own separate file however whenever when ever I appendage it to my table scene (Image 1) I get what you see in the table image (a gray un texturized goblet) How do I get the same texturized goblet  seen in image one to appear in image one Additional info: the table image is blender rendered where as the goblet is cycle rendered. Thanks so much any thing helps!

Comment: Why are you mixing materials from two different render engines?

Answer (score 2):

Blender renderer cannot read cycles materials, you'll have to build a Blender Internal material for the goblet: just create it from scratch and assign all the previous textures in the right slots.